# PanelBars / Accessing Nested Controls MVC

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, telerik, asp.net-mvc-3

thanks in advance for your help, I would like to know if its possible to create a Panelbar with Accessing Nested Controls (eg: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/applicationscenarios/accessingnestedcontrols/defaultcs.aspx) scenario using Telerik MVC (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/panelbar/) or jquery. I need to add a create view using more than one table and I need to add product -> productvariant -> product picture in sequences.
thank you so much,
sebastian.

Comment: I am not sure what the exact question is. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Those are Webform based controls that don't play nice with MVC.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you have an idea of how to implement a create record form that needs multiple tables where pk of the second table requires record on the first one to be created first all in one view? brgds!

Comment: @sebastian_h - Probably, ask a new question.